# XPath expression doesn't match "%20" on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xpath

I'm having a problem while looking for a string with `%20` in a xml using xpath.
I'm trying to match this string this:

```
 <navMap>
    ...
    <navPoint id="navpoint-2" playOrder="3">
        <navLabel>
            <text>Title</text>
        </navLabel>
        <content src="My%20book%20OK.xhtml"/>
    </navPoint>
    ...
</navMap>
```

This is my query:

```
//ncx:content[@src='My%20book%20OK.xhtml']/../ncx:navLabel/ncx:text
```

It works for elements with `@src` not containing `%20`, but not for the one given above.

Comment: Your query will never return anything for this input as `<content/>` is an empty element. Please post input _matching_ to your question / code.

Comment: I have just edited my question, when the src has no %20 it works, the problem is the %20. Thanks!!

Comment: My expected output is "Title". This part it's working fine i say that if the src doesn't have %20 like Mybook.xhtml the result is ok, but for some reason if the src has %20 there is no results.

Comment: My previous comment was plain wrong; sorry about that, doing too many things at the same time right now. Your query works for me (using BaseX as query processor), so this seems to be a problem with the one you use. Which one is it? By the way, `//ncx:navPoint[ncx:content[@src='My%20book%20OK.xhtml']]/ncx:navLabel/text` would probably be a more elegant query.

Comment: I'm using Xpath from an IOs app, maybe this is the problem...

Comment: I retagged a little bit and removed irrelevant tags and added iOS. Maybe you should add two further tags, one for the language (Objecte-C?) and the XML-framework used. This should help to draw attention of people developing for the same platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
//content[contains(@src,'%20')]
```

Comment: Sorry i wrote wrong my question, now is updated. What i want is to match de src with exactly the same text